# Fragment onAttach/Create/CreateView methods not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, initialization, android-support-library

I'm writing a simple `Activity` which should retrieve and show some data in a `Fragment` containing a `ListView`. The problem is that I'm not able to access the `ListView` because none of the `on*` methods seems to be called.

The fragment has a `LinearLayout` which gets populated dynamically by the code in `onCreateView`. The `Activity` creates the `Fragment` in `onCreate` and adds it to its layout using the `FragmentManager` returned by `getSupportFragmentManager`(As a side note: I'm using the support-v4 library).

Adding some `Log.d` calls in the `onAttach`/`onCreate`/`onCreateView` methods clearly show that none of them is called at all.

What am I doing wrong?

The activity:

```
public class CharactersActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private MainCharactersFragment mainFragment = null;

    private String[] charnames = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // R.layout.characters contains only a LinearLayout with id characters_fragment_container
        setContentView(R.layout.characters);
        if (mainFragment == null) {
            mainFragment = new MainCharactersFragment();
            //Add the fragment to the activity's layout.
            //Taken from Google's tutorials.
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.characters_fragment_container, mainFragment).commit();
            //I'd expect onCreateView to be called during this commit, but it is not called.
        }
        //Loads some data to display
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String[] filenames = intent.getStringArrayExtra(PortableDnDActivity.CHARACTERS_FILENAMES);
        this.charnames = new String[filenames.length];
        for (int i=0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
            this.charnames[i] = getCharacterName(filenames[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // Set the ListAdapter to show the data.
        Log.d("MyLog", "           HERE            ");  // Shown by logs
        ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_characters_view); // This is null
        Log.d("MyLog", "The view is null:" + (view == null));
        mainFragment.setCharsAdapter(this, this.charnames);
        Log.d("MyLog", "                 HERE           2222"); //NOT shown by the logs
    }
```

The activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/characters_fragment_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment:

```
public class MainCharactersFragment extends Fragment {

    public ListView charsList;
    public Button newCharButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // The following is never shown in the logs
        Log.d("MyLog", "                HERE                ");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_characters_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void setCharsAdapter(Context ctx, String[] data) {
        // Raise NullPointerException because at this moment
        // findViewById(R.id.main_characters_view) returns null
        charsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, R.id.main_characters_view, data));
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        Log.d("MyLog", "            onAttach called           "); //Never shown
    }
}
```

The fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/main_characters_view"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="0.5"
              />
    <Button android:id="@+id/new_character_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/new_character"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What if you have MainCharactersFragment extend ListFragment instead of Fragment? You can create a new project using the MasterDetailFlow template as an example of how to use a ListFragment.

Comment: @BenJakuben Using a `ListFragment` is not an option because I'll add some other `View` later, and thus I need a custom fragment. Anyway, now I'll try to see if using a simple `ListFragment` still raises this errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the NPE is confusing things. Comment that out of your `onStart()` so you can address it separately.

Once you do that, you will see you have a few cases of falling to call the `super` method.  Once in `MainCharactersFragment.onAttach()` and once in `CharactersActivity.onStart()`.  Add those two calls in, clean, and try again.

Given those changes, your code ran fine for me.

Comment: I'd already figured this out 3 minutes ago replacing my fragment with a plain `ListFragment`. The missing `super` call in `onAttach` was voluntarily, because I thought that maybe the error was caused in the super-class implementation and thus putting a `Log.d` after would not show if the method was called or not. But I add that `onAttach` only later.